# Use PhantomJS crowbar to extract D3-created SVG from webpage on local webserver

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to extract an SVG I created with D3 from a webpage.  Because I'm using d3.csv to read in my data for the image I'm using a local web server.  I've been experimenting with using Andrew Reagan's `phantom-crowbar.js` code (https://github.com/andyreagan/phantom-crowbar) and while that works great for extracting SVG from `http://` pages and `file:///` pages, when I try to extract from my page with address `http://localhost:8000` then I receive the following message:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'svg.setAttribute')

phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():32
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():55
Evaluated our code
```

"`Evaluated our code`" is the message you usually receive when the SVG has been successfully extracted but the output file is empty.

I'm new to JavaScript, PhantomJS and working in the browser with D3 so any help would be much appreciated. I really have no idea why the local server page should behave differently.

Comment: please provide you code

Comment: If you just need to do this once, you can use the developer tools in your favorite browser to copy the SVG.

Comment: Have you tried to run PhantomJS with `--web-security=false`?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up asking Andrew Reagan and he got back to me very quickly, the issue was that I was setting the SVG `"id"` attribute within a function in my script.  Since I was using `d3.csv()` to read in a csv and generate my image everything was wrapped within this function. I set the `"id"` attribute outside of this using

```
d3.select("svg").attr("id", mysvg)
```

and now phantom-crowbar.js works no problem.

@Stephen I need to generate and save multiple D3 images so I needed a way to extract the SVG programmatically and Andrew's `phantom-crowbar.js` is the best approach I've tried if other people are looking to do something similar. `SVG Crowbar` bookmarklet is great if you need to do this only on occasion.

Comment: It seems to me that your answer references some things that are not shown in the question. Please update the question so that the answer makes sense.